# Make div clickable, but not text inside

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a div clickable without a link. The click simply sets a session variable to the id of the div. My problem is, the span,h3 and p parts get registered individually from the div. This throws off the styling as well as the behaviour.
**EDIT**: I might not have made my problem clear enough: Setting the session variable is not the problem, I simply didn't display the js code. When I clicked anywhere in the div that is not covered by text it works fine. However, when I click somewhere where there is text, the text is clicked and not the div. Since the text has no id the session variable doesn't get set properly and the styling of my "active" class gets applied to the text and not the div.

The div's code:

```
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="task-option-button panel-body" id="create_your_own">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>
        <h3>Individual Task</h3>
        <p>Create a new task without a template</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The CSS

```
.task-option-button >span,h3,p {
    z-index:1;
}
.task-option-button{
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align: center;
    padding:10px;
    height:150px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    z-index:10;

}

.task-option-button:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    border-bottom:5px solid #D8853B;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
```

I was playing around with z-index, but to no avail. Even worse, on another page, this construction is working flawlessly. A clickable panel with different elements inside, and everywhere I click I click on the panel, not the text. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: `user-select:none; pointer-events:none;` - on the text itself not button

Comment: Feels a bit hacky but it did the trick. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT

I've made a codepen which behaves as expected; check against what you have to see if there's a mistake.

## [CODEPEN EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/65bef5a5f27657ba5a313c2f3bcb77f0)

why wouldn't this work? not sure how you're setting session variables, but I'll use a cookie.

```
var createCookie = function(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

$('#create_your_own').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr(id);
    createCookie('divID', id, 10);
});
```

Comment: I am doing this anyway, I have to set the session variable somehow. This is not connected to the problem.

Comment: It does provide an answer @tom, just not the one the OP wanted. "I am trying to make a div clickable without a link."

Comment: I don't know how else to help you, man, or I would. Perhaps you could try asking a different way.

Comment: @Todd Now it may answer the question. Before that edit it was just a question with some code OP should try.

Comment: lol. being and containing a question are different. It answered the question asked, but I assumed that he may've tried that. I just don't want to insult people by plopping up some playschool jquery.

Comment: I have edited my original question. The setting of the Session variable is not at all the problem. It is purely the html/css that is not behaving how I want to to behave.